# Tomcat Hangs On Response

Tags: struts2, tomcat7

I am kind of getting lost with this one, we are using Tomcat7 on Windows 2008 server which is running behind IIS. The application framework is Struts2 and we have kept logs in the first and last line of a struts action method. Also, we have turned on tomcat access log valve. The problem,

1) The logs in the action class method states that the request enter and leave the method in a few milliseconds, post completing the entire processing.

2) The tomcat access valve logs show the same request taking more then a 10 minutes.

Where would the response be getting stuck in this case. No clue on where to start debugging, as this happens completely randomly.

Comment: Windows 2008 ? IIS ? You're lucky it starts :D

Comment: @Andrealigios unfortunately a situation and design I cannot help. Initially tomcat6 was used and I have been told it was working fine. Since migration to tomcat7 the issue started.